# Customize pop-up indicator position and size for power and volume

Tags: sound, icons, gnome-shell, indicator

When changing the volume (by pressing the keyboard keys) this icon pop ups, right in the middle of the screen:

[image: Volume Image]

I would like to change both the position and the icon, ideally to a more discreet location on the screen. I've seen other questions asking how to change the icon completely, but haven't found how to change the position and size.

Edit: I suppose whatever process works for the volume indicator also works for the brightness indicator. (Not sure if "indicator" is the right word for these icons.)

Comment: If you decide to remove it, you can do it in dconf:
`dconf write /org/mate/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/enable-osd 'false'`

Comment: remove what? maybe you meant this as a comment on another answer?

Comment: To remove the icon altogether. I know the author asked a slightly different thing (how to modify the icon), but with this answer I provide a possible workaround

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Better OSD](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1345/better-osd/) is what you're looking for. It works very well on Ubuntu 18.04.
It is a Gnome extension, that is available via Ubuntu Software too.

After installing it via Ubuntu software, you can access to its settings via **Gnome tweaks>Extensions** (if you don't have Gnome Tweaks, you can install it from Ubuntu Software too).
Here are some screenshots of what I got after playing around with the extension settings:

[image]

You can even resize the volume indicator

[image]

**PS:** If it doesn't work for you directly after installing it, you may need to restart the gnome shell environment ("logout and login again", or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then <kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>)